# IcedTea Doesn't Run Properly in Firefox

Tags: 12.04, firefox, java, openjdk, icedtea

I have Java 7 installed for Ubuntu 12.04 and I have IcedTea installed in Firefox (33.0). Some Java plugins are not working correctly. For example: starting from  the IcedTea-Web-Tests (see the IcedTea wiki) I tried two tests:

1. The WebEx test session (http://www.webex.com/test-meeting.html). This runs correctly once. Subsequent attempts to run this without restarting the browser will fail.
2. The Java version verification (http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp). This does not run.

Failure is indicated by a big grey box and nothing happening (sometimes I get prompted to run the applet first, but then nothing happens). I turned on logging and checked the log files in ~/.icedtea/logs/ Whenever something fails, as above, the reported error is

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/libjawt.so already loaded in another classloader
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1931)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1851)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1062)
    at JDownload.loadJava7Lib(JDownload.java:125)
    at JDownload.init(JDownload.java:73)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:436)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I can't find any specific help for this error, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to execute the Sun-applets flawlessly you need to install Oracles (Sun) Java engine.

Duinsoft in the Netherlands have done an excellent job of automating install and udates, by entering a few things in the Aptitude packet manager.
Here is the How to and pacakeges:
http://www.duinsoft.nl/packages.php

Unfortunately IceTea java dosnt work with all java-sites!

Good luck.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks, if a little depressing. I was obviously too optimistic about IcedTea. Now all of the tests work OK, but my WebEx session still doesn't work properly. I don't think that's a straightforward Java issue so I've contacted WebEx support.